# Invalid URI Scheme Python , MongoDB Error

Tags: python, mongodb, pycharm

I was trying to create a project in pycharm which uses MongoDB and Pymongo. 
But I encountered the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/IngeniousAmbivert/PycharmProjects/terminal_blog/app.py", line 6, in <module>
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
File "C:\Users\IngeniousAmbivert\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 400, in __init__"%s" % (entity[:idx],))
pymongo.errors.InvalidURI: Invalid URI scheme:  mongodb
```

For the following code :

```
import pymongo

uri = " mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
database = client['stack']
collection = database['students']
students = collection.find({})
print(students)
```

Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 5):

Okay . I figured it out . Just needed to remove the space

```
uri = " mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/" = Error
uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017" = No Error
```

Output :

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x038B58D0>
```

Damn ! I keep forgetting Python is a space sensitive programming language

Answer (score 0):

[i was getting the uri invalid error. for that i was searching this web, here is one solution. it was already implemeted in my script (client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri))
but still showing the error. ]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32646731)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).